# JavaScript adding an onclick event to a element

Tags: javascript, html, css

My aim is to add an onClick event to an element when the screen is below 700px wide and to remove the clickable area if its above 700px. Am I going about this in a good way? How would I add onClick="myFunction()" to a div in HTML?

```
myFunction();
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    myFunction();
});
function myFunction() {
    var i = document.all?document.body.clientWidth:window.innerWidth; 
    if(i > 701) {
        // Adds onClick
    }
    if(i < 701) {
        // Removes onClick
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you added the resize event but with `click` instead of `resize`

Answer (score 3):

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
element.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1o3hjqs/5/)

Answer (score 0):

As already said by Timovski to assign onClick to div ,
give some id to the div and declare var.

```
var element = document.getElementById('divID');
```

than simply add eventListener to the declared var.