# How to interact my button with my function

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in JavaScript, I am trying to click on a button and I have to display an alert message. My button does not interact?

My HTML is:

```
<body>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <button id='b1'>Click on button</button>
</body>
```

My problem is on Javascript

```
function myFunction(){
    ???? = document.getElementById('b1');
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Comment: This is a question for a JavaScript tutorial and not SO. You should be able to find the answer with any decent search provider or at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: There is a direct example of this on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript adding an onclick event to a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801990/javascript-adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-element)

Comment: @ControlAltDel Please, for the love of God, don't reference W3 Schools. It is well known to have incomplete, inaccurate, or out of date information like the link you shared which still advises to use inline HTML event attributes like `onclick` in 2020, [which should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Re: onXXX methods: You are completely right with this, if perhaps a little over the top :) I stopped using them (because you have to) when I discovered Content-Security-Policy. Still, I think it's useful to know about them, if only to know why you shouldn't use them. Re: w3schools: This site is very useful. Nearly everything I know about CSS I learned on w3schools. In terms of JS, I found there `datalist` and `input` (for the different HTML 5 types) pages useful. I'm just sayin...

Comment: @ControlAltDel But here's the thing about W3 Schools, why go to a site that is incomplete, inaccurate, or out of date, when you can go to Mozilla Dev. Network and still get all that information, but from the authoritative source? It's just as easy to learn there. There is **no** reason to use W3 Schools. And, on the `onXyz` attributes, there is also **no** reason to know about them, since they shouldn't be used anymore. The reason we still see so many people using them is because so many people keep these abominations alive. Let them die. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something to happen when the user clicks, you must add an event handler (or callback function) to the element in question. That is done with the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method of the element:

```js
// Get a reference to the button
let btn = document.getElementById("b1");

// Add an event handler for the click event
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
    alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<button id='b1'>Click on button</button>
```

FYI: There is a much older way of doing this that you will still see people use today because they don't fully understand how event handlers work. That way uses embedded event attributes in the HTML, like `onclick`. [Do not use these!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)

Comment: Thank your code works but on my IDE, nothing is happening?

Comment: The JavaScript must be placed at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `body` tag so that by the time it is encountered, the HTML button will have been parsed into memory.

Comment: Thank you Scott ! ;-)